# how to use ORDER BY RAND() with where condition

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.0

i want to display my products using ORDER BY RAND() with where condition

**This is my query**

```
$qry="select * from product_tbls where category_tbls_id=".$data["0"]["product_tbls"]["category_tbls_id"];
```

i know this normal working query without where condition

```
$qry="select * from product_tbls ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,6;";
```

but i want to use where condition

Thanx in advance.

Comment: the ordering is irrelevant. the syntax is `select ... from ... where ... order`, regardless of what you're ordering by.

Comment: what is the issue you are getting?

Comment: For heavans sake. **Try it** if it does not work **LOOK at the manual**

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry man but no one wants to come here to ask direct, i was trying. but i couldn't figure out.

Comment: When using `ORDER BY RAND()` don't be surprised when your query performance absolutely *tanks* once you get more than a few dozen rows in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is what you're asking: You should use "WHERE" before ORDER BY rand().

Example:

```
$qry="select * from product_tbls WHERE a = 'b' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,6;";
```

You forgot to concatenate the rest of the query.

```
$qry="select * 
      from product_tbls 
      where category_tbls_id=".$data["0"]["product_tbls"]["category_tbls_id"]." 
      ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,6";
```

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple use of the `where` condition with `order by`

```
$qry="SELECT *  FROM product_tbls
  WHERE category_tbls_id = '".$data["0"]["product_tbls"]["category_tbls_id"]."'
  ORDER BY RAND() 
  LIMIT 0,6;"
```

Comment: unexpected ' " " '

Comment: check the updated answer. I missed `"`.

Comment: thanx for your help but, just little " this

Comment: @Vky : :), No issue. Glad you have fixed that.